# How to auto answer "yes" in window powershell?

Tags: powershell

```
$LanguageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$LanguageList.add("En-US")
Set-WinUserLanguageList $LanguageList
$LanguageList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$LanguageList.Remove($LanguageList[1])
Set-WinUserLanguageList $LanguageList
```

I can run this code in window powershell just fine but I need to hit "enter" after running code in the lines 3 and 6. So, I want to auto 'yes' in this situation. It will make me run this code without hit "enter" button.
I try echo, -confirm$false but it doesn't seem to help me. Please anyone help me. Sorry, If my english is a bit bad. I'm also a newbie for window powershell.

Comment: `Set-WinUserLanguageList $LanguageList -Confirm:$false` <-- use `:` to bind `$false` to the switch parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reply to Mathias R. Jessens answer
Whoever wrote and accepted this messed it up.
You have to add `-Force` for `Set-WinUserLanguagList`.
The Docs say `Confirm:$false` is default, but looks like it does nothing.